# Python TypeError with *args

Tags: python

Forgive my ignorance, I am new to Python and I can't seem to find the answer on Google. Perhaps I'm just not searching the right keywords.

I have a basic function as follows:

```
class Basic(object):
    def Process(*values):
        for i in range(len(values)):
            value = int(values[i])
            print value

b = Basic()
b.Process(4, 5, 6)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Basic'

I'm sure it is something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It means exactly what it says: something that got passed to `int` was a `Basic` instance, rather than a string or a number. Why is that? Well, look at what `int` is called with, and where those values come from... By the way, please please please don't write this `for i in range(len(values)):` nonsense. You are going out of your way to make things harder for yourself. Iterate directly: `for value in values:`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning. I'm a c# programmer... so I'm very open to better ways of programming Python. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to give `self` as an argument to Process:

```
def Process(self, *values):
```

Comment: Ahh Ha! Thank you so much. I will accept in 11 minutes when it let's me :)

Answer (score 1):

Right, self.  Instance methods should be lower cased and classes shouldn't be written: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0 (since I'm already writing this answer).

```
class Basic(object):

    def process(self, *values):
        for v in values:
            v = int(v)
            print v

b = Basic()
b.process(4, 5, 6)
```